# Prove or disprove: $R^{n+1} \supseteq R \cap R^2 \cap \cdots \cap R^n$ for every binary relation $R$ on a set of size $n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, semigroups-and-monoids

Prove or disprove: $R^{n+1} \supseteq R \cap R^2 \cap \cdots \cap R^n$ for every binary relation $R$ on a set of size $n$.

I have verified the statement for $n \leq 4$ with a Mathematica code.
I have tried to prove the statement by considering the digraph $\Gamma(R)$ associated to $R$.  I tried to use this fact: If $(x,y) \in  \bigcap \limits_{\ell=1}^n R^\ell$ then there is a directed walk in $\Gamma(R)$ from $x$ to $y$ of every integer length $\ell \leq n$.  This implies that $\Gamma(R)$ contains a cycle.  I would like to show that this also implies that there is a directed walk in $\Gamma(R)$ from $x$ to $y$ of length $n+1$.

Comment: "where $R$ is a binary relation on a set of size $n.$" If you mean "for _every_ binary relation $R$ on a set of size $n.$" I think it would be far better to phrase it that way. Using "where" as a quantifier can be confusing sometimes because it can be unclear which quantifier it is.

Comment: What is $\ R^k\,?$

Comment: @bof, thank you, that's what I was guessing. However, in mathematics, I refuse to be a hacker. If I don't get the info from the author then I go away from their text.

Comment: I edited the question to change "where $R$ is a binary relation" to "for every binary relation $R$." If the latter is meant, it is clear, but the way it was phrased originally leaves me not entirely sure. So if I'm wrong that that was what was intended then this will need to be edited again to correct my misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $k_n$ be the least integer $k$ such that, for any digraph $D$ of order $n$ and any vertices $x,y\in D$, if there are $x$-$y$ walks of length $1,\dots,k$, then there are $x$-$y$ walks of all positive integer lengths.

**Theorem.** $k_1=1$ and, for $n\ge2$,
$$k_n=n-1+\max\{g(m)-m:0\le m\le n-2\}$$
where g(m) is [Landau's function](https://oeis.org/A000793), the maximum order of an element in the symmetric group $\mathbf S_m$.

(So $k_n=n$ for $n\le8$, *i.e.*, [YCor's example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458853/prove-or-disprove-rn1-supseteq-r-cap-r2-cap-cdots-cap-rn-for-every/458876#458876) with $n=9$ vertices is as small as possible.)

Trivially $k_1=1$; we consider $n\ge2$. I have to show that
$$k_n=f(n):=n-1+\max\{g(m)-m:0\le m\le n-2\}.$$
Note that $f(n)\ge n$ since $g(0)=1$.

To show that $k_n\le f(n)$ it will suffice to prove the following:

**Lemma 1.** Suppose $x,y$ are vertices in a digraph of order $n\ge2$, and suppose $k\ge f(n)$. If there are $x$-$y$ walks of length $1,\dots,k$, then there is an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k+1$.

**Proof.** Assume for a contradiction that there are $x$-$y$ walks of length $1,\dots,k$ but none of length $k+1$.

Note that no cycle contains $x$ or $y$. For if $C$ were a cycle of length $m$ containing $x$ or $y$, then by adding $C$ to an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k+1-m$ we would get an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k+1$.

Let $C_1,\dots,C_t$ be a maximal family of (vertex-)disjoint cycles with respective lengths $m_1,\dots,m_t$. Let $m=m_1+\cdots+m_t\le n-2$ and let $L=\operatorname{LCM}(m_1,\dots,m_t)\le g(m)$. Now
$$k\ge f(n)\ge n-1+g(m)-m\ge n-1+L-m,$$
whence
$$k\ge k+1-L\ge n-m\ge2.$$
Let $W$ be an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k+1-L$. Then $W$ is disjoint from the cycles $C_1,\dots,C_t$, as otherwise there would be an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k+1$. So $W$ has at most $n-m$ vertices, and length $k+1-L\ge n-m$, so $W$ contains a cycle, which is disjoint from $C_,\dots,C_t$, contradicting the assumed maximality of that family of disjoint cycles.

We have shown that $k_n\le f(n)$. We will show $k_n\ge f(n)$ by generalizing YCor's construction.

**Lemma 2.** $k_{n+1}\ge k_n+1$.

**Proof.** Take a digraph of order $n$ with vertices $x,y$ such that there are $x$-$y$ walks of length $1,\dots,k_n-1$ but none of length $k_n$. Add a vertex $y'$ and an arc from $y$ to $y'$. In the resulting digraph of order $n+1$ there are $x$-$y'$ walks of length $1,\dots,k_n$ but none of length $k_n+1$.

**Lemma 3.** $k_n\ge g(n-2)+1$ for $n\ge2$.

**Proof.** Write $g(n-2)=\operatorname{LCM}(m_1,\dots,m_t)$ where $m_1+\cdots+m_t=n-2$. Consider a digraph consisting of disjoint cycles $C_1,\dots,C_t$ of respective lengths $m_1,\dots,m_t$ and two additional vertices $x$ and $y$. Draw an arc from $x$ to $y$; draw arcs from $x$ to one vertex in each cycle; and draw arcs to $y$ from all but one vertex in each cycle, chosen so that there is an $x$-$y$ walk through $C_i$ of length $k$ iff $k\not\equiv1\pmod{m_i}$. Thus there is an $x$-$y$ walk of length $k$ iff either $k=1$ or else $k\not\equiv1\pmod{g(n-2)}$.

We finish the proof of $k_n\ge f(n)$ by proving the following:

**Lemma 4.** If $0\le m\le n-2$ then $k_n\ge n-1+g(m)-m$.

**Proof.** By Lemmas 2 and 3, since $n\ge m+2$,
$$k_n\ge n-(m+2)+k_{m+2}\ge n-m-2+g(m)+1$$
$$=n-1+g(m)-m.$$

Comment: I like to edit in links to answers, comments, etc. when I can. I find that @YCor's answers are so often referenced that "Edited in link to @‍YCor's answer" is now suggested in my browser's auto-complete.

Comment: Can this be improved to the effect that for every digraph with $n\le 8$ vertices, $\bigcap_{i=1}^n\subset R^k$ for all $k\ge n+1$? (and not only for $k=n+1$)? Actually, for general $n$, I find it natural to ask what is the minimal $k_n$ such that for every binary relation $R$ on an $n$-element set, we have $\bigcap_{i=1}^{k_n}R^i\subset \bigcap_{i\ge 1}R^i$.

Comment: @bof ah thanks. Note that $k_n\ge n$: just consider the digraph with vertices $\{1,\dots,n\}$, edges $(i,j)$ for $i<j$: then $(1,n)\i 
 R^k$ iff $1\le k<n$.

Comment: @ bof.  I searched OEIS for the sequence $k_n$ but did not find it.  I think this sequence would be a welcome addition to the data base.  Would you consider submitting it?

Comment: @GeoffreyCritzer Thanks for the suggestion, but to do that I'd first have to learn how to submit a sequence to OEIS. Maybe there's nothing to it, but I don't feel like looking into it. Anyway I have no special responsibility for this sequence; as I learned from other answers and comments here, the problem it addresses was solved years ago; all I did was provide a self-contained detailed exposition. You can submit the sequence to OEIS if you want to.

Answer (score 15):

This is false as shown by the following digraph.
From $x$ there is an edge to $v_p$, from $v_p$ there is a cycle of length $p$ to itself, and from $v_p$ there are $p-1$ different paths to $y$, of lengths $1,2,\ldots,p-1$.
Then using these $\Theta(p^2)$ vertices we can get from $x$ to $y$ through $v_p$  along a walk of length $\ell$ for any $\ell\not\equiv 1 \pmod p$.
If you repeat the above construction for every prime $p\le N$, and also add the edge $xy$, then the shortest missing length is $1+\prod_{p\le N \text{ prime }} p$, which is much bigger than $\sum_{p\le N \text{ prime }} \Theta(p^2)$.
It would be a nice problem to determine exactly up to what length you need walks to get walks of any length.

**Update.** Apparently, Aleksei has solved essentially the same question [five years ago](https://mathoverflow.net/a/315173/955), with an asymptotically optimal bound.

Comment: If I'm correct the smallest $n$ for which this yields counterexamples is $n=20$. Namely for $n=20$, take for $p$ the numbers $4$, $5$ only ($p$ prime doesn't matter, coprime is the point). This gives $20$ vertices ($x$, $y$, the $4$-loop, the $5$-loop, $0+1+2$ more vertices for arrows from $v_4$, $0+1+2+3$ more for the arrows from $v_5$), while the first forbidden length is $21=4\times 5+1$.

Comment: Or even better, $n=12$ with choosing $p=3,4$, and the following trick: identify the middle vertex in the length 2 arrows from $v_3$ and $v_4$.

Comment: Variant with 9 vertices: $x,v_2,v_5,y$. Write the cycle $v_2$ as $b_0,b_1$, and the cycle $v_5$ as $c_0,\dots,c_4$. Join $x\to y$, $x\to b_0$, $b_1\to y$, $x\to c_0$, $c_i\to y$ for $i\neq 3$ (and the cycles, i.e. $b_0\to b_1\to b_0$, $c_0\to c_1\to\dots\to c_4\to c_0$). Then for $m\ge 0$ there is a path from $x$ to $y$ of length $m$ iff $m$ is nonzero modulo $10$.

Comment: For your last question, $2^N$ is enough -- consider, for each $k$, the set of points which are reachable from $x$ in exactly $k$ moves. There are $2^N$ different sets, so they are eventually periodic before $2^N$'th step, and if in every one of them we had $y$, then $y$ will be every time afterwards. Your example is something like $\exp(\sqrt[3]{N})$, but we can improve it to $\exp(\sqrt{N})$ by treating all the paths of length $s$ coming from different $v_p$'s as the same path. So we are between $\exp(\sqrt{N})$ and $\exp(N)$, not too close, but not too far either.

Comment: You can get paths of length $1,\dots,p-1$ from $v_p$ to $y$ using just $p-2$ vertices (other than $v_p$ and $y$). Just take a path of length $p-1$, and include edges from $v_p$ to all other vertices on the path. This reduces the size of the graph to $O\bigl(\sum_{p\le N}p\bigr)$.

Comment: I completely forgot that I've answered a related question some 5 years ago [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/315116/given-any-finite-relation-r-what-is-the-cardinality-of-langle-r-rangle-un) ... The number of possible sets is of course at most $2^N$, but it is also bounded by $\exp(\sqrt{N\log (N)}(1+o(1))$ (in fact, by the Landau function plus a tiny error). So, the example of @EmilJeřábek is almost optimal.

Comment: On second thought, the paths from $v_p$ to $y$ are not needed at all; one can just include edges from all but one vertex of each cycle to $y$. I see that this was meanwhile used in YCor’s answer. So it’s really $2+{}$ the sum of lengths of the cycles.

Answer (score 9):

domotorp's lovely [solution](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458862) is by far the best one, but here is an explicit counterexample for $n = 10$, I wonder if it's computationally tractable to figure out the max $n$ for which your statement holds.

$S = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$

$R = \{(0, 1), (0,6), (0,9), (1,2), (1,9), (2,3), (2,9), (3,4), (3,9), (4,5), (4,9), (5,1), (6,7), (6,9), (7,6)\}$

(It's not a typo that $8$ is not used.) This $R$ should have $(0,9) \in R \cap \dotsb \cap R^{10}$ but not $R^{11}$.

Comment: How did you construct this example?

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of size 9 inspired by [domotorp's anwer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458862/14094), where I only consider the primes $2,5$, and where I replace the additional long arrows from the basis of the cycles with arrows from the vertices themselves, which avoids additional vertices, and where I change the congruences to precisely forbid $n+1=10$ instead of $11$.

In words: I have 9 vertices: the initial and terminal vertices $x,y$, a $2$-cycle $v_2=\{b_0,b_1\}$, a $5$-cycle $v_5=\{c_0,\dots,c_4\}$. Join: $x\to y$, $x\to b_O$, $x\to c_0$, $b_1\to y$, $c_i\to y$ for $i=0,1,2,4$ (i.e. not for $i=3$), and the cycles $b_0\to b_1\to b_0$, $c_0\to c_1\to c_2\to c_3\to c_4\to c_0$.

Then for $m\ge 0$ there is a path from $x$ to $y$ of length $m$ iff $m$ is nonzero modulo $10$.

Here's a picture of the digraph:[image]

Comment: I don't know if $n=9$ is minimal, but $n\le 6$ can easily be discarded by hand.

Comment: [Link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/458903/14094) to bof's answer proving that $n=9$ is minimal.